Apply each cell of column a condition and replace the value in cells in R
I have the dataframe below:
    > last_t_df3

      A1BG       A2M     NAT1      NAT2  SERPINA3
    1 1.943765 0.0000000 1.271231 0.0000000 0.0000000
    2 1.419931 0.3045321 2.507409 0.0000000 4.8022908
    3 0.000000 0.0000000 2.993064 0.5276899 2.0130009
    4 0.000000 1.2882883 3.048454 2.7974017 11.2820992
    5 0.000000 0.0000000 3.642756 0.0000000 9.5866993

And cutoff list for each column below:
> cutfoo2
$A1BG
[1] 1.176439

$A2M
[1] 5.307673

$NAT1
[1] 4.867072

$NAT2
[1] 3.425465

$SERPINA3
[1] 9.234962

I would like to apply cutoff for each corresponding column and if the cell is below its cutoff, I want to replace it with 'NO'.
I tried for loop like below:
for (row in 1:nrow(last_t_df3)) {
for (col in 1:ncol(last_t_df3)) {
  g <- last_t_df3[row, col]  
  if (g < cutfoo2[[col]]) {
    last_t_df3[row, col] <- "NO"
  }
}
}

It works for small size of dataframe (last_t_df3), but actually my real dataframe is in  33 12623 dimension and my for loop does not work for that one and for example even 11.2820992 in SERPINA3 column is replaced with NO in real dataframe weirdly.
Do you have any suggestions to make for loop better or alternative way?
Thanks in advance!

The columns in your data are numeric and you are trying to replace some numbers with a character string. It will convert the whole column to characters. Better to replace it with NA. It would be much easier (and faster) if you either convert the data to matrix or long data frame.

Something like last_t_df3[last_t_df3 < cutoff] <- NA ?

Or, if the names are not in order last_t_df3[names(cutoff)][last_t_df3[names(cutoff)] < cutoff] <- NA

Solution: Applying Cutoffs to a Data Frame
There are multiple ways to apply cutoffs to your data. Below are three approaches:

Approach 1: Using a for Loop
You can use a for loop to iterate through the columns and apply the cutoffs.
# Example data
ExampleData <- data.frame(
  FirstCol = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 15),
  SecondCol = c(20, 21, 30, 35, 56),
  ThirdCol = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1),
  FourthCol = c(2, 7, 6, 5, 9)
)

# Cutoffs for each column
Cutoffs_list <- list(
  FirstCol = 7,
  SecondCol = 21,
  ThirdCol = 0.5,
  FourthCol = 8
)

# Applying cutoffs
for (i in seq_along(ExampleData)) {
  ExampleData[, i] <- ifelse(ExampleData[, i] < Cutoffs_list[[i]], "NO", ExampleData[, i])
}

print(ExampleData)


Approach 2: Using dplyr (from the tidyverse package)
A more concise and modern way is to use mutate from the tidyverse package:
library(tidyverse)

# Example data
ExampleData <- data.frame(
  FirstCol = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 15),
  SecondCol = c(20, 21, 30, 35, 56),
  ThirdCol = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1),
  FourthCol = c(2, 7, 6, 5, 9)
)

# Applying cutoffs with mutate
ExampleData <- ExampleData %>%
  mutate(
    FirstCol_bis = ifelse(FirstCol < Cutoffs_list[[1]], "NO", FirstCol),
    SecondCol_bis = ifelse(SecondCol < Cutoffs_list[[2]], "NO", SecondCol),
    ThirdCol_bis = ifelse(ThirdCol < Cutoffs_list[[3]], "NO", ThirdCol),
    FourthCol_bis = ifelse(FourthCol < Cutoffs_list[[4]], "NO", FourthCol)
  )

print(ExampleData)


Approach 3: Using Vectorized Logic
A compact way to apply the cutoffs directly is by leveraging vectorized logic. Here's how:
# Example data
ExampleData <- data.frame(
  FirstCol = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 15),
  SecondCol = c(20, 21, 30, 35, 56),
  ThirdCol = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1),
  FourthCol = c(2, 7, 6, 5, 9)
)

# Cutoffs for each column
Cutoffs_list <- list(
  FirstCol = 7,
  SecondCol = 21,
  ThirdCol = 0.5,
  FourthCol = 8
)

# Applying cutoffs
for (i in seq_along(ExampleData)) {
  ExampleData[[i]] <- ifelse(ExampleData[[i]] < Cutoffs_list[[i]], "NO", ExampleData[[i]])
}

print(ExampleData)

Alternatively, if you want to overwrite only the values meeting the condition without creating new columns:
ExampleData <- data.frame(
  FirstCol = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 15),
  SecondCol = c(20, 21, 30, 35, 56),
  ThirdCol = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1),
  FourthCol = c(2, 7, 6, 5, 9)
)

ExampleData[ExampleData < sapply(Cutoffs_list, as.numeric)] <- "NO"

print(ExampleData)


Summary
Each approach has its use case:

Approach 1 (for loop): Simple and works for any data frame.
Approach 2 (dplyr): Modern, concise, and readable, especially for complex manipulations.
Approach 3 (vectorized logic): Compact and efficient for smaller data sets.


If using mutate, consider using across also. In addition, try learning about Map

Here base R:
df <- last_t_df # Copied data to avoid in place replacement
i <- match(names(df), names(cutfoo2)) # Indexing just in case the list and columns do not match
df[t(t(df[i]) < unlist(cutfoo2[i]))] <- "NO"
df
      A1BG A2M NAT1 NAT2   SERPINA3
1 1.943765  NO   NO   NO         NO
2 1.419931  NO   NO   NO         NO
3       NO  NO   NO   NO         NO
4       NO  NO   NO   NO 11.2820992
5       NO  NO   NO   NO  9.5866993


In tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
last_t_df %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(.x, .x<cutfoo2[[cur_column()]], "NO")))
      A1BG A2M NAT1 NAT2   SERPINA3
1 1.943765  NO   NO   NO         NO
2 1.419931  NO   NO   NO         NO
3       NO  NO   NO   NO         NO
4       NO  NO   NO   NO 11.2820992
5       NO  NO   NO   NO  9.5866993

